# notification button not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

i m creating custoom notification in my app.the notification shows up,but when i click on button,the button doesnt work.i dont know what to do.i looked in all the answer on stackoverflow but didnt get the idea.so,please help me.

this is code for notification

```
private void customNotification() {

    Intent closeButton = new Intent("Download_Cancelled");
    closeButton.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, closeButton, 0);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music)
            .setContent(notificationView)
            .setChannelId(ID);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, pendingSwitchIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
```

this is broadcast activity

```
public class NotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

this is manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".BlankFragment2$NotificationBroadcast">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Download_Cancelled" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: have you tried adding .addAction in Notification.Builder ?

Comment: ok,let me try..